# How to do conditional date formatting in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file which has date value like "20181029". Note that this column can have blank values as well. I want to convert this column as date - data type like (2018-10-29), for blank columns i want to have blank value in dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the read_csv method with the argument parse_dates. The value of this argument should be the name of the column in your csv file that contains the dates:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', parse_dates=['some_col'])
```

Comment: Good answer, using `parse_dates` with `pd.read_csv` should be preferred versus `pd.to_datetime` once the data has been read in.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it after reading the file too:

```
import datetime as dt
df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y%m%d'))
```

**Edit**

As @jezrael suggested in comment you can use `pd.to_datetime` too.

```
df['datetime'] =pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format = '%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: why not pd.to_datetime ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dt.strftime(date_format:str)` for the date_format conversion.

For instance,

`df['date_column'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Try the following to handle null values,

```
df['date_column'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if x else "")
```